# Mapping a function in R with multiple arguments

Tags: r, purrr

I am looking for the R way (preferably "Tidyverse way") to map a function to multiple arguments.

I have created a function with multiple arguments:

```r
product <- function(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4){
  return(c(a, b, c, d, a*b*c*d))
}
```

I am looking for the most convenient way to use the function multiple times with different parameters. I am able to use the `map` functions from the `purrr` package (to some extent), but there are two scenarios in which I am stuck:

**1) If I only want to alter** `c`

**2) If I want to alter for example `c` and `d`***

My solution is rather cumbersome. I either create a wrapper around the function for my specific needs (so a lot of wrappers...) or use the `pmap` function from the `purrr` package, e.g.:

```r
a <- list(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
b <- list(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
c <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
d <- list(4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
    
pmap(list(a, b, c, d), product)
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

If you only want to change `c`

```
map(1:4, product, a = 1, b = 2, d = 4)
```

If you only want to change `c` and `d`

```
pmap(list(1:4, 11:14), product, a = 1, b = 2)
```

---

And a suggestion: don't use `c` as an object name. `c` is the function that creates a vector. Something else is better coding style.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that even the shorter variant `pmap(list(c = 1:4, d = 11:14), product)` is possible!